# Do bullets have travel time?

Tags: battlefield-1

Since Battlefield 1 is my first Battlefield game, I sometimes find myself struggling to play a match or two. Old habits kick in from games like Call of Duty or other hitscan shooters, and I have trouble tracking and hitting targets.

Is there bullet travel time in Battlefield 1, for all guns? Sometimes it feels like I'm tracking and shooting perfectly, but my bullets are missing.

Comment: Also, keep in mind, if you're moving, your accuracy goes down.  Standing has higher sway versus crouch, which has higher sway versus prone (which can be an issue for accuracy).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, all weapons have bullet speed and drop, you can see these statistics when you are comparing weapons.

Granted, a lot of them travel fast enough that you can treat them as hitscan and be pretty OK, especially in close range engagements, but for really long range engagements like sniping you may need to lead the target a bit.